# How to fix "password fields present on an insecure (http //) page" without SSL?

Tags: php, wordpress

I read the articles here and on google, that I have to buy a "SSL certificate", but this is unfortunately not really low priced. **My question is:** why I get this "warning message" not on an CMS like wordpress in the backend (user password field)? What they doing differently? Because this page is also not on an https.

Can anybody explain me what is the difference? How can I fix this without SSL?

Comment: Certificates are actually free now. https://letsencrypt.org/ | yes it's real, no it's not a scam. So now there's absolutely no reason to not use HTTPS when dealing with sensitive data

Comment: @JimL, thats really interesting, thx for the link! But I also want to know what they doing differently ... they must do something more secure.

Comment: how to fix what without ssl ? whats the warning, what code have you tried to fix it ??

Comment: Do you have a link to your site? I've checked a few wordpress sites without https and FF complains about all of them

Comment: Yes, I have a passwordfield on an php (method="post"), thats what firebug see as risk.

Comment: @JimL Sorry, I run it just local (xampp). But at my backend firebug doesnt complain about the user password field (user profile page) ...